# Plotting well log interval data in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to be able to produce a simple well log graph with ggplot2. Test data is simple:

```
From    To  Lith
0   25  A
25  50  B
50  75  C
75  100 B
100 125 C
125 150 A
150 175 B
175 200 C
```

The plot should be in a form of a strip, colored according to *lith* column with correctly displayed depths and should look something like this ("SLF" used instead of "Lith"):

[image: A sample well log]

As you can see, certain units repeat down the column and I need them to be in their correct place.
I was hoping there is a simple way to force *geom_bar* or *geom_col* to simply draw the data as it is, without summarising it in any way, but it seems I was wrong.

How should I go about doing this? Which *geom" should I use?

TIA

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here rather than the table you wrote. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Thanks, Shawn. I watched the video and will keep it in mind in the future. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's fairly straighforward to do this using `geom_rect` instead of `geom_bar`

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = 1, y = From, fill = Lith)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0.5, xmax = 1.5, ymax = From, ymin = To)) +
  scale_y_reverse(name = 'Depth') +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 2), name = NULL) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'OrRd')
```

[image]

---

**Data taken from question in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(From = c(0L, 25L, 50L, 75L, 100L, 125L, 150L, 
175L), To = c(25L, 50L, 75L, 100L, 125L, 150L, 175L, 200L), Lith = c("A", 
"B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `geom_rect`. You have the min and max heights so it's fairly easy.

```r
x <- 'From    To  Lith
0   25  A
25  50  B
50  75  C
75  100 B
100 125 C
125 150 A
150 175 B
175 200 C'
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(x), header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(fill = Lith)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = From, ymax = To)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 8)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks. And your plot reverses the y axis, which I hadn't noticed. To the OP, add `scale_y_reverse(name = "Depth")` like in [Allan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73869963/8245406)  to get an y axis like in the question.

Comment: Thanks, Allan and Rui :)